# Why are top tags sorted by amount of posts?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

After some searching I don't believe this question has been asked before, but it may seem similar to other questions so bear with me.

I was looking at my profile and saw that for the tag [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) I've got 6 posts with a total score of **one**, whereas I've got 1 post with a score of **eight** for the tag [sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) as seen below:

[image: Bootstrap]

[image: Sublime]

But on my Stack Overflow profile under the Top Tags section the tags are sorted in descending order by the amount of posts made in a specific tag, rather than the total score in the tag, as shown below (notice how the [sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) tag isn't present):

[image: Top Tags]

So the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag is appearing under top tags, rather than the [sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) tag, even though it has a lower tag score.

I'm wondering why this is the case, as the phrasing "Top Tags" seems to suggest that the tags are ordered by the total score in a tag.

Ordering by amount of posts in a tag (in my opinion) doesn't reflect a user's knowledge in that tag, rather it just shows how much they post. Whereas tag scores provide a rational figure to show how beneficial answers/questions are to other users on the site

Comment: so you want a feature request?

Comment: Not really, I'm more just wondering as to why the tags are ordered that way, rather than changing it

Comment: So considering your edge case, very atypical but expected because the numbers are almost zero, you want to know on an option-less screen why  the coders did it that way? An opinion or a comment from the devs?

Comment: I dont think it is an edge case, as it could easily apply to any user with a large number of posts in a tag, but a greater score in a different tag. I'm simply looking for a reasonable explanation of why the tags are sorted by post amount and not score as it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: It's not universally true - on my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=profile), Java appears before C# even though I have made more posts in C# than in Java.

Comment: It is ambiguous; "top tag" could refer to the tag you're most active in (# of posts) or the tag you're most *successful* in (# of points). In this case it looks like the devs picked the former meaning over the latter.

Comment: I find the behaviour quite reasonable. Otherwise providing just a single decent answer to a question that somehow becomes popular could show a tag as one of your top tags even though you don't actually know a lot about it, and that technology (or whatever) is something you didn't touch in the following 8 years... I believe it is better to provide information that *also* relate to the user activity in the profile, instead of just "hey by a stroke of luck I managed to post a well received answer to a question with a tag to which I don't really know anything about and don't even use".

Comment: On a closely related note, why isn't there an option to *sort a user's tags by number of posts*?  I would prefer to view them this way so that I can see areas of interest and contribution -- which I think can be far more interesting than what tags were in use on highly-voted answers.  As it is, when looking through my own tags, I have to browse by name in order to find certain favorites.  Votes are an indication of popularity, which is fine, but there's more to life than popularity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is perfectly reasonable and should not be changed.

First, you should know that the general rule is that the tags are sorted by score, not number of answers. What you see is an edge case where one of your top tags (when it comes to votes) is a tag you only have a single answer in.

<sub>This doesn't happen for me, so I have to show it on someone else's profile:</sub>

Let's look at [koala_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049063/koala-dev?tab=tags) who has provided a [very high scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3/18153551#18153551) to a question tagged: [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) and [centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centering).

Now, this of course gives him a very high score those tags:

```
                      Score / Posts
css:                   1960 / 196   
twitter-bootstrap:     1735 / 104
twitter-bootstrap-3:   1368 / 35
centering:             1165 / 1
and
html:                  617 / 183
jquery:                506 / 254
```

These are his top scoring tags. The top-tags on the front page are [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

What is most indicative of his skills? 1165 points on one post in [centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centering), or 617 points on 183 posts in [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)?

Having one or two super popular answers would skew the Top-tags section so that only those minor tags would be shown. For that reason, tags where you have very few answers are omitted from that section. Perfectly reasonable, and definitely the way it should be done (IMHO).

Comment: I don't think it should be changed either I was just curious. And it seems your right, I also think they maybe they take into account both number of posts and score of posts. As some users I've seen have one of their top tags with a slightly lower number of posts than another, but a higher score (if that makes sense). Nevertheless this answer proved good reasoning which is what I was after